# Can't understand how a SDI works

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to create a text editor by using a blank project. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around SDI's. What is this doing exactly? Also how do I use the classes?

```html
auto pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(BaseDocument),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(BaseFrame),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(BaseView));

if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

I tried using the document like this:

```
auto xtra = (BaseDocument*)pDocTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(newDlg.currPath);
```

It returns a "File Cannot be opened" Error.

Edit: When i try to just tried to skip the dialog i created and just run the "Template" code there is an error when it reaches

`if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo)) 
    return FALSE;`

Here is the whole application:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(BaseApp, CWinApp)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CWinApp::OnFileNew)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinApp::OnFileOpen)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BaseApp::BaseApp() {
SetAppID(_T("AbduTextEditor"));
}


BaseApp::~BaseApp()
{
}
BaseApp theApp;

BOOL BaseApp::InitInstance() {
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

CWinApp::InitInstance();

SetRegistryKey(_T("AbduTextEditor"));
LoadStdProfileSettings(5);

m_pRecentFileList->ReadList();

auto pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(BaseDocument),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(BaseFrame),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(BaseView));


if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
/*
BeginningDlg newDlg;
BOOL newdoc;

for (auto i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    newDlg.rf.Add(m_pRecentFileList->operator[](i));
}

switch (newDlg.DoModal()) {
case 1:
    newdoc = FALSE;
    break;
case 3:
    newdoc = TRUE;
    break;
default:
    return FALSE;
}
auto xtra = (BaseDocument*)pDocTemplate- 
>OpenDocumentFile(newDlg.currPath);*/

CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);


AfxInitRichEdit2();

EnableShellOpen();
RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE);

if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;



m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

return TRUE;
}


int BaseApp::ExitInstance()
{
m_pRecentFileList->WriteList();

return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
}
```

Here is where `mydlg.currPath` is set

```
void BeginningDlg::OnBnClickedOpenbutton(){
CString string = _T("Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");

CFileDialog filedlg(TRUE,nullptr,nullptr, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST| 
OFN_ENABLEINCLUDENOTIFY,string,this);

filedlg.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = path;
INT_PTR pInt = filedlg.DoModal();

if (pInt == IDOK) {
    currPath.Append(filedlg.GetPathName());
    EndDialog(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you read the MSDN documentation for `AddDocTemplate`? What in the documentation is not clear? Regarding "File Cannot be opened": did you check the value of `newDlg.currPath`?

Comment: I realized that this is how you initialize the application. But the document is there, how exactly am I suppose to open a txt file? Am i using the pointer correctly? The document exists.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger. MFC comes full source, you can debug into it. My crystal ball says that `newDlg` is a `nullptr`. I down voted because you don't show the relevant sources and seemingly did not try to debug.

Comment: I can post the whole application if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `ON_CREATE` message for a frame.